# Graph. Divide the vertices into a small number of groups.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading this book "Mathematics: A Very Short Introduction", and I can't really understand what the author mean by this:

"Once we have represented the problems in this way, our task in both cases is to divide the vertices into a small number of groups in such a way that no group contains two vertices linked by an edge. (The graph in Figure 5 can be divided into three such groups, but not into two.)"

[image: Here's the picture of the graph]

How do I divide it into 3 groups?

Comment: Yes. I can. One minute.

Comment: Nevermind, another answer did it way better ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is according to the colors in the picture below (red, blue, and purple are the three groups).

[image]

But I think the intent of the author is not for you to try to figure out the division, just as a "by the way".

Comment: I just was wondering how to do that :) Thanks!